# SVG text size limitation

Tags: html, css, svg, graphics

So I'm converting from DWFx to SVG (for reasons), and the scale of the transformations from one to the other seem not to work.  That is, it seems that if the 'em' size of a  element is beyond a certain size, that the browser just truncates the text size to 1,000,000 px, for example, even though it will get scaled by the containing  element's transformation matrix.

I tried adding text-rendering="geometricPrecision", and it failed (things just disappeared - maybe addition scaling would be necessary).

Here is the SVG that I have.  Why does the text fail to scale to larger sizes?  It ultimately causes the text not to be visible because everything else scales properly (paths), but with a transform of 9.8e-7 the text size seems to get scaled to 0 because the actual x,y and size properties seem to have an upper bound.

Here is a fiddle of the issue as well: [EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/qy825rur/2/)

```
<svg  width="500px" height="500px" style="background-color: #eee;">
<g transform="matrix(0.000009,0,0,0.000009,0,0)" >

<!-- ----------------------------- -->
<!-- This line shows the text fine -->
<!-- ----------------------------- -->
<text  x="10000000" y="20000000" font-size="190000em" fill="#000000" font-family='Arial'> 
        Hello World
</text>

    <font-face 
    font-family="Arial"
    font-stretch="normal"
    units-per-em="4096"
  />

<!-- ----------------------------- -->
<!-- Increase fontsize by 1000 and -->
<!-- and the text stays same size  -->
<!-- WHY???                        -->
<!-- ----------------------------- -->  
<text  x="10000000" y="30000000" font-size="190000000em" fill="#000000" font-family='Arial' > 
        Hello World 2
</text>

</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: The short answer is that browsers (and other user agents) never expect you to have font sizes in the millions of px, so they don't use number formats that can hold those values.  Can you scale the graphical coordinates when you do the conversion?   With really large coordinate values, you will even have problems drawing shapes in some programs (e.g. Firefox and Cairo) which use fixed-precision number formats instead of floats for storing coordinates.

Comment: Well, my current plan is to extract all the elements that are text based, and rollup the matrix operations myself in JS, and then scale the coords/em of each text entry directly, and then store the text in a <g> that's outside of any of the <g> that holds the paths (which are transformed by the parent <g> transforms).

It just seems odd to me that the browsers can hold the <path> elements coordinates, which are enormous, but can't hold the <text> element coords, since both will be scaled by the same <g> parent transform.

Comment: I suspect its a CSS vs SVG thing: SVG is designed for scalable coordinate spaces, so the numbers aren't expected to directly translate to screen pixels, but font-size is a basic CSS property.  That said, be sure to test your basic graphics on all browsers before you do too much more work, because as I mentioned some Firefox builds have problems with large numbers even for coordinates.